# How do i verify user input id either rock, paper or scissors using the OR (||) logical operator?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

How do i make the code print results of winner and the counter to the console?
The top part of the code runs fine now. my current challenge is that the code does not go through the if / else conditional and does not print to the console/ The conditional part of the code does not seem to run.
i have tried the == and === and none of them worked. did i miss something?

```
    //get computer choices
    comChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; 

    function playRound() {
    //get user input
    userInput = prompt("please enter rock, paper or scissors"); 
    //verify its in lowercase
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase(); 

    if (
        userInput === "rock" ||
        userInput === "paper" ||
        userInput === "scissors"
    ) {
        function comrand() {
        // function selects a random computer choice
        randomChoice = comChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
        comChoices.length)];
        return randomChoice;
        }
        window.alert(comrand());
    } else {
        // veirfy user input
        window.alert("please enter rock, paper or scissors or check your 
    spelling");
        playRound();
    }
    }

    //initialize count default
    userWin = 0;            
    comWin = 0;
    draw = 0;


    //conditionals to determine winners
    if (userInput == "rock" && randomChoice == "scissors"){               
        userWin++;
        console.log("You win!!! (rock crushes scissors)");
    } else if(userInput  == "scissors" && randomChoice =="rock"){
        comWin++;
        console.log("Computer wins!!!(rock crushes scissors)");
    } else if(userInput == "scissors" && randomChoice == "paper"){
        userWin++;
        console.log("You win!!! (Scissors cuts paper)");
    } else if(userInput == "paper" && randomChoice == "scissors"){
        comWin++;
        console.log("Computer win!s!! (Scissors cuts paper)");
    } else if(userInput == "paper" && randomChoice == "rock"){
        userWin++;
        console.log("You win!!! (paper covers rock)");
    } else if(userInput == "rock" && randomChoice == "paper"){
        comWin++;
        console.log("Computer win!s!! (paper covers rock)");
    } else {
        draw++;
        console.log("game is a draw");
    }
     
    

    if (userWin === 5){                                              // 
    conditions to determines the overall winner
        console.log("User wins the game");
    } else if (comWin === 5){
        console.log("computer wins the game");
    } else {
        console.log("the game is a draw");
    }

    playRound();
```

Comment: Welcome!
For starters, `(userInput !== "rock" || "paper" || "scissors")` will always be true because `"paper"` and `"scissors"` are truthy.
You could use `(userInput !== "rock" || userInput !== "paper" || userInput !== "scissors")`, or `(!comChoices.includes(userInput))`.

Comment: I'd create three buttons...

Answer (score 0):

I just reversed the if condition. It works fine.

```js
//get computer choices
comChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

//initialize count default
userWin = 0;
comWin = 0;
draw = 0;

function playRound() {
  //get user input
  userInput = prompt("please enter rock, paper or scissors");
  //verify its in lowercase
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

  if (
    userInput === "rock" ||
    userInput === "paper" ||
    userInput === "scissors"
  ) {
    randomChoice = comChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * comChoices.length)];
    //conditionals to determine winners
    if (userInput == "rock" && randomChoice == "scissors") {
      userWin++;
      console.log("You win!!! (rock crushes scissors)");
    } else if (userInput == "scissors" && randomChoice == "rock") {
      comWin++;
      console.log("Computer wins!!!(rock crushes scissors)");
    } else if (userInput == "scissors" && randomChoice == "paper") {
      userWin++;
      console.log("You win!!! (Scissors cuts paper)");
    } else if (userInput == "paper" && randomChoice == "scissors") {
      comWin++;
      console.log("Computer win!s!! (Scissors cuts paper)");
    } else if (userInput == "paper" && randomChoice == "rock") {
      userWin++;
      console.log("You win!!! (paper covers rock)");
    } else if (userInput == "rock" && randomChoice == "paper") {
      comWin++;
      console.log("Computer win!s!! (paper covers rock)");
    } else {
      draw++;
      console.log("game is a draw");
    }

    if (userWin === 5) {
      // conditions to determines the overall winner
      console.log("User wins the game");
    } else if (comWin === 5) {
      console.log("computer wins the game");
    } else {
      console.log("the game is a draw");
    }
    window.alert(randomChoice);
  } else {
    // veirfy user input
    window.alert("please enter rock, paper or scissors or check your spelling");
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    playRound();
  }, 1000);
}

playRound();
```

Comment: wow thanks, that worked. i added the second part of the code which would not run the conditionals. please help me take a look. it does not print the result and counter to the console.

Comment: @Michael now check it.

Comment: thank you so so much. i now understand what i missed and why. you are awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
    if(userInput !== "rock" || "paper" || "scissors"){     // veirfy user input
      window.alert("please enter rock, paper or scissors or check your spelling");
      playRound();
    }
```

Do this

```
    if(comChoices.includes(userInput )){     
       // veirfy user input
    } else {
       // not verifying user input
    }
```